# Trying to implement a wheel picker in React Native

Tags: react-native, components

I'm trying to create a React Native wheel picker but I'm stuck with how to proceed. So I kind of have something to start with. A view of a box with an animated view inside of it. Right now it moves along the y-axis as it should, but the view doesn't move right.

This is how it renders. It renders exactly how I intend it to:
[image: Component at render]

Now when I move this, everything just moves up like this:
[image: Component being moved]

I want the numbers to move but not be seen outside of the orange box. I want the grey lines to not move. And I also want the visibility to change as the numbers move towards and away the center, as well as a snapping mechanism when I let go so that the wheel snaps when a particular value is in the center.

I tried using a FlatList but it renders the list to be all the way at the top and messes with other components.

I also don't want to use any platform-independent libraries.

```js
import { useRef, useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  PanResponder,
  Animated,
} from "react-native";

export default (props) => {
  const values = useRef(props.values);
  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  const pan = useState(new Animated.ValueXY())[0];
  const panResponder = useState(
    PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: () => {
        console.log("granted");
        pan.setOffset({
          x: pan.x,
          y: pan.y._value,
        });
      },
      onPanResponderMove: Animated.event(
        [
          null,
          {
            dx: pan.x,
            dy: pan.y,
          },
        ],
        { useNativeDriver: false }
      ),
      onPanResponderRelease: () => {
        pan.flattenOffset();
        console.log("released");
      },
    })
  )[0];

  return (
    <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "orange" }}>
      <Animated.View {...panResponder.panHandlers} style={pan.getLayout()}>
        <Text style={style.textDisplacedTwice}>
          {values.current[currentIndex - 2]}
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.textDisplacedOnce}>
          {values.current[currentIndex - 1]}
        </Text>
        <View style={style.pickedValueBorder}>
          <Text style={style.textLabel}>{values.current[currentIndex]}</Text>
        </View>
        <Text style={style.textDisplacedOnce}>
          {values.current[currentIndex + 1]}
        </Text>
        <Text style={style.textDisplacedTwice}>
          {values.current[currentIndex + 2]}
        </Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  textLabel: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#f3f4f8",
    fontSize: 28,
    marginHorizontal: "15%",
  },
  textDisplacedOnce: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: 0xf3f4f899,
    fontSize: 28,
    marginHorizontal: "15%",
  },
  textDisplacedTwice: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: 0xf3f4f833,
    fontSize: 28,
    marginHorizontal: "15%",
  },
  pickedValueBorder: {
    padding: 5,
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderColor: "#444742",
  },
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a package?
Try [react-native-wheel-pick](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-wheel-pick) , it works on both android and ios.

```
    import { Picker } from 'react-native-wheel-pick';
    
    const items = useCallback(() => (
    [1,2,3].map((item, index) => ({
      label: item,
      value: item,
    }))
  ), [])

<Picker
  selectedValue={items ()[1]?.value}
  pickerData={items ()}
  onValueChange={(value: string) => { console.log(value) }}
  textColor={'white'}
  isShowSelectBackground={false}
  selectBackgroundColor={'transparent'}
  textSize={23}
  selectLineColor={'grey'}
  style={{
  backgroundColor: 'black',
  }}
/>
```